# code blocks running xcode/visual studio project

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am a student studying statistic.

And my C++ teacher asked us to submit project always by code::block.

However, I am more likely to work with mac os.

And code::blocks not running good with mac.

Is that possible to convert Xcode/Visual studio project to code::block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that code::blocks or XCode are IDEs (Integrated Development Environments) which means basically they are text editors. What you need to build a program is a compiled and an IDE usually comes with a compiler bundled with it. What an IDE usually does is keep all you files together and add some info like compiler switches and so on.

This job is usually handled by a separate program, the build tool. The make program is probably the oldest of these programs and you need to have an idea of how they work.

To get to your question you can build your program with whatever editor/IDE you want, then you may need to get your .cpp files and import them in another one.

Comment: Hence, what i need to do just copy and paste .cpp and .h to code::block. :)

Comment: You could just import them in a code::block project

Comment: thanks I will try. To create a project from existing code files?

Comment: Create a new one and then add files...you need to play a bit to get used to those tools. They work all much the same way.